# Nested jQuery code always returning 'undefined' first?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a nested jquery ajax call in the `.done` of the parent.
It works, however, there is always `undefined` returned at the beginning when `getProjectFiles(projectid)` is called, whether its `data` is empty or not.

**js:**

```
function getProjects() {
  //...some typical jquery code
  ajaxRequest.done(function(data) {
    //...append some stuff to html
    $('#mydiv').append('some html stuff' + getProjectFiles(projectid));
  }
}

function getProjectFiles(projectid) {
  var func = 'getProjectFiles';
      var args = [projectid];

      var formData = { 
        'action': func,
        'args': args
      };
  $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../includes/ajax.php',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json'
      });
  ajaxRequest.done(function(data) {
    if(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i,v) {    
        $('div#'+projectid+'.project-box-files').append(v['filename']);
      })  
    }
  });
}
```

**php:**

```
//these are in a separate functions.php file
function pdoSelect($sql, $args) {
    $pdo = dbConnect();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
    $returnval = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($returnval);
}

function getProjectFiles($someParameters){
    //db insert
    $sql = 'SELECT blah blah';
    $args = array($someArgs);
    return pdoSelect($sql, $args);
}

//this one is in ajax.php
$func = $_POST['action'];
$args = $_POST['args'];
call_user_func_array($func, $args);
```

Is `getProjectFiles()` being "async called" even *before* `projectid` gets filled in? Or do I need some sort of "callback" format for calling `getProjectFiles` inside `getProjects`?

Comment: I never got an answer to this, so I just included the "get project files" in the "get projects" JSON result. Still want to know what's giving that "undefined" 1st result though